# Access first element of json array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my JSON object

```
{
    "errors": {
        "product_name": {
            "message": "Product name is required",
            "name": "ValidatorError"
        },
        "category": {
            "message": "Category is required",
            "name": "ValidatorError"

        }
    }
}
```

My aim is to access the first "message", though it can be access via

```
 errors.product_name.message
```

this is not the goal, my goes is to get first message without using the "product_name" object, like

```
errors[0].message
```

Comment: there is no array in what you've shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to iterate on the errors and fetch the message property

```js
const obj = {
 "errors": {
  "product_name": {
   "message": "Product name is required",
   "name": "ValidatorError"
  },
  "category": {
   "message": "Category is required",
   "name": "ValidatorError"

  }
 }
};

const [,value] = Object.entries(obj.errors)[0];
console.log(value.message);
```

Comment: Worth noting that even using Object,entries() the *first* may not always be the same property key. Whole thing seems like an XY problem

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know, an `object` is not a `Set`. The order is not always the same (it depends on the iterator implementation).

It *usually* gives you the order of the declaration keys but it doesn't need to be true.

Then, some ways to get what you want.

With `Object.keys`:

```
const keys = Object.keys(obj.errors);
const firstError = obj.errors[keys[0]];
```

With `Object.entries`:

```
const entries = Object.entries(obj.errors);
const firstError = entries[0][1];
```

Then, if you don't need all the keys you can just stop at the first one:

```
function getFirstKey(obj) {
  for (const k in obj) {
    return k;
  }
}

const firstError = obj.errors[getFirstKey(obj.errors)];
```